# How to format android.widget.TextView text so that & does not appear as &amp;

Tags: android, android-layout

I am setting Tweets in a android.widget.TextView, and & is ending up formatted as

```
          &amp;
```

How should I format so that special characters like & show correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Html.fromHtml()`:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml("&amp;"));
```